# SQL: Return Column Name With Highest Value From Subquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Working with a large data set in Big Query that assigns a specific grade to an item. For example:

```
fruit   | grade  | 
----------------
 apple  |   A    |
 orange |   B    |
 apple  |   C    |
 apple  |   A    |
 orange |   D    |
 orange |   D    |
 apple  |   A    |
 orange |   D    |
```

To summarize these, I wrote out some COUNT & CASE functions, like:

```
  COUNT(CASE WHEN fruit = apple AND grade = 'A' then 1 else NULL end) as apl_a,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN fruit = orange AND grade = 'A' then 1 else NULL end) as org_a
```

It results in something like below:

```
fruit   | apl_a  | apl_b  | apl_c | 
-----------------------------------
 apple  |   3    |   0    |   1   |
 orange |  null  | null   |  null |
```

I have been attempting to have this computation happen in a subquery, and then use the alp_a or org_a to populate in a summary of the results, showing me what the most common grade each fruit has. Something like the below

```
OUTPUT

 fruit  | grade  | 
----------------
 apple  |   A    |
 orange |   D    |
```

How would I be able to utilize what was counted, and provide me with a simplified output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select fruit, string_agg(grade order by weight desc limit 1) as grade
from (
  select fruit, grade, count(1) weight
  from `project.dataset.table`
  group by fruit, grade
)
group by fruit
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Comment: wanted to add - my answer is addressing exactly the question as it was asked  - `Return Column Name With Highest Value From Subquery` . But it does not mean it is the best way to address the use-case you described inside your question. Unless you really need result based on exact counts  - @gmb's answer is to go with!

Comment: access to limit in string_agg is unique to google bigquery, string_agg itself isn't in the standard - I believe listagg was introduced in SQL:2016 but not widely adopted as yet

Comment: Question is clearly tagged with google-bigquery tag. The dialect that is used in BigQuery is officially called BigQuery [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) :o) BigQuery Standard SQL complies with the SQL 2011 standard, and has **extensions** that support querying nested and repeated data.

Comment: duh, of course it is, everyone wants their own standard

Comment: sure. true - still love those extensions and love using them. they give some spice into query :o)

Comment: consider also voting up the answer if it helped :o)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the *mode*, that is the most frequently occuring value per group. Some databases (such as Oracle, or Postgres) have a built-in function for that - but not Big Query.

You could use approx_top_count`()` instead:

```
select fruit, approx_top_count(grade, 1)[offset(0)].value as grade
from mytable
group by fruit
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach which reduces the number of case expressions you need involves use of `row_number() over()` to extract only the wanted rows from a result. Note that in the case of a tie in the count the higher grade is selected due to the `order by` inside `over()`. (see "pear" in the final result)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable(
>    fruit VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
>   ,grade VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
> );
> INSERT INTO mytable(fruit,grade) VALUES ('apple','A');
> INSERT INTO mytable(fruit,grade) VALUES ('orange','B');
> INSERT INTO mytable(fruit,grade) VALUES ('apple','C');
> INSERT INTO mytable(fruit,grade) VALUES ('apple','A');
> INSERT INTO mytable(fruit,grade) VALUES ('orange','D');
> INSERT INTO mytable(fruit,grade) VALUES ('orange','D');
> INSERT INTO mytable(fruit,grade) VALUES ('apple','A');
> INSERT INTO mytable(fruit,grade) VALUES ('orange','D');
> INSERT INTO mytable(fruit,grade) VALUES ('pear','A');
> INSERT INTO mytable(fruit,grade) VALUES ('pear','B');
> ```

> ```
> select
>      fruit
>    , grade
>    , count_of
> from (
>     select
>         fruit
>       , grade
>       , count_of
>       , row_number() over(partition by fruit order by count_of DESC, grade) AS rn
>     from (
>         select
>             fruit
>           , grade
>           , count(*) AS count_of
>         from mytable
>         group by
>             fruit
>           , grade
>         ) derive1
>     ) derive2
> where rn = 1
> ```

> ```
> fruit  | grade | count_of
> :----- | :---- | -------:
> apple  | A     |        3
> orange | D     |        3
> pear   | A     |        1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b758cb0854b6202f3cadaa7b5c26f81b)* (example uses postgres)